# Spectacle for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm looking for a tool to arrange windows on Windows. On macOS I'm satisfied with Spectable https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle.

I remember I used Sizer on Windows 7 (http://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/) but these days I'm using Windows 10.

The thing I miss the most is the snap to other windows or snap to the borders/corners.

Any recomendation?

Answer (score 1):

No need for any 3<sup>rd</sup> party tools. There are already built-in shortcuts to snap or move windows

Shortcuts available since Windows 7:

- Snap to left/right: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>
- Move window to the left/right monitor: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>

New shortcuts since Windows 10:

- Snap to top/bottom left: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, then <kbd>Up/Down</kbd>
- Snap to top/bottom right: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, then <kbd>Up/Down</kbd>

Comment: And, if you want even more control, [Windows 10 PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys) includes [FancyZones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones) which is a tiling window manager

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Microsoft PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/). It is several tools combined in one application. With FancyZones, you could set zones and arrange your desktop to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is [WindowGrid](http://windowgrid.net/).

I too used the original sizer, and a few years ago I found it's updated sibling [Sizer4](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/), and the search eventually landed me with WindowGrid.

It splits the screen to a predefined grid, and then with a simple mouse gesture (while dragging the title bar, right-click the mouse, drag, then release) you can place the window very quickly and very easily.

[image: WindowGrid Demonstration - Animated GIF]

If that doesn't suite your fancy, there are a few other solutions out there that might be of interest:

- As mentioned by [modlin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/80738/76723) - `Microsoft PowerToys` has `FancyZones` which is pretty awesome.
- If you want cutting-edge, check out the Windows 11 preview, it has a new feature the call [Snap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu), which will make the maximize button do some screen positioning magic - this one feels closely tied to above mentioned `FancyZones`.
- [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/#intro)
- [Preme for Windows](http://www.premeforwindows.com/) - I actually use this alongside WindowGrid, for it's other features.

** While WindowGrid and Preme havn't been updated in years, I've been using these for a long time on Windows 10 and Windows Server environments, and had no issues with them. Hope they are still useful when you (and any other reader) reads this.

Comment: Wondering which one is closer to macOS Spectable?

Comment: In your post, if you list the specific features you're looking it to mimic, I might be able to help. Never used a Mac (other then helping out friends)